# Proving continuity of composition of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, function-and-relation-composition

I need to prove the following theorem:

Given $f(x)$ with domain $Df$ and $g(x)$ with domain $Dg$:

With $f$ and $g$ above, let $a$ be in the domain of $f(g(x))$. Then $f(g(x))$ is continuous at $a$ if $g$ is continuous at $a$ and $f$ is continuous at $g(a)$.

I am at a loss of how to approach this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Proof:

1. The definition of continuity is
   $$
    \forall \epsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0 : 0 < |x − x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x)−f(x_0)| < \epsilon
   $$
2. 

Comment: Start with the definition?

Comment: Please use the search tool before asking, I'm sure this question have been asked before

Comment: I would have thought so, but I couldn't find anything proving the general case. If you know of one I would greatly appreciate that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g:D_g\to \mathbb R$

and

$f: D_f \to \mathbb R$

$a \in D_g.$

if
g is continuous at a

$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=g(a)$

and

f continuous at g(a)

$\lim_{x \to g(a)}f(x)=f(g(a))$

and

$\color{red}{g(D_g) C D_f}$

( included)

then

$lim_{x \to a}f(g(x))=f(g(a)).$

which means $fog$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: You cannot talk about limits if $a$ and $g(a)$ are not cluster points.

Answer (score 0):

showing that the preimage of all opens is open is enough to show that the function is continuous

let $U$ open in the image of the domain of $fog$, show that $(fog)^{-1}(U)$ is open.
$(fog)^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ and since $f$ is continuous so $f^{-1}(U)$ is open and since g is continuous then $g^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ is open so $f$o$g$ is continuous